# How to use rank function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records between fifth to tenth. 
I am using below query in sql server

Plz make me correct

```
SELECT ID,
       code,
       first name,
       last name,
       RANK() OVER(ORDER BY code) AS rk
FROM tbl_em_employees
WHERE rk BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

Its giving me error

> Invalid rk.

Comment: Note that `OFFSET/FETCH` will not take into consideration the rank value; i.e. if you have multiples ranked anywhere in 1-4 these will be included. Further if you have multiples between 5 and 10 you will not retrieve all of them.
Better to put your query in a sub-select and select from that `WHERE Rnk BETWEEN 5 AND 10`
As Tim has said below

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference the column alias in the `WHERE`, therefore you have to use a subquery or a common-table-expression(CTE):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    Select ID, code, first name, last name, 
        rank() over (order by code) as rk 
    from tbl_em_employees 
)
SELECT ID, code, first name, last name
FROM CTE
WHERE rk between 5 and 10
```

Comment: Does this really work with spaces in column names? Aren't square brackets around `first name` and `last name` neccessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, code, first name, last name FROM
(
    Select ID, code, first name, last name, 
        rank() over (order by code) as rk 
    from tbl_em_employees 
)

WHERE rk between 5 and 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use rank function like that:-

```
RANK ( ) OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

For more reference check this link :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql

Comment: MD. Khairul Basar why are you dislike my post ?? any issue in my post

Comment: First, probably @MD. Khairul Basar was not the one who give you a -1, he updated your answer to remove unneeded spaces from your code. Then, your question was downvoted because questions that are almost only a link are considered low quality, you just put the link and copied the parameters from the docs, you didn't explain anything. Finally, that *doesn't solve* the problem, he doesn't have a problem with `RANK()` but with the column alias, see the most voted answer.